# Quick.db + Discord.js Leader Board

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

Hello I Was Making A Leader Board For My Xp System And The Points One Worked!

But The Mention Gives An Unknown Id And Its The Same Always

[Here Is What It Shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIFaP.png)

So The Code Is In Quick.db If You Can Help Me It Would Mean The World For Me

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === prefix + "top") {
        let xp = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`guild_${msg.guild.id}_xp`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)
        xp.length = 10;
        var message= "";
        var i = 0;
        for (i in xp) {
          message += `${xp.indexOf(xp[i])+1}# | <@${xp[i].ID.split('_')[1]}> | ${xp[i].data}  \n`;
        }
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(msg.author.username , msg.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true}))
            .setColor('#FFD700')
            .addField(`Top Text Xp`, message)
            .setTimestamp()
            msg.channel.send(embed)
        }
})
```

**So Yea Peace Out**

Answer (score 0):

```js
message += `${xp.indexOf(xp[i])+1}# | <@${xp[i].ID.split('xp')[1]}> | ${xp[i].data}
```

Just replace `_` with `xp`. it will help.